# UDP Hole Punching - Destination unreachable

Tags: c#, udp, p2p

I'm trying to make p2p connection using UDP hole punching method, but I always get ICMP packet with Destination unreachable status.

At first, there is created an UDP connection to server:

```
        send = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        server = new UdpClient(send);
        server.AllowNatTraversal(true);
```

without any direct connection (no ip, no port, just endpoint on random port).

I send some packets to server with direct `server.send([..],[..],serverip,serverport)` on server's ip and port and obtain information (remote IP, port used to connect to server) about another peer

Now I'm trying to make hole punch with sending simple UDP packets on peer's IP:PORT using server connection (but again with direct `server.send([..], [..], peerip, peerport)`). I know that the first packet is always dropped, so I'm sending it 50 in 100ms intervals, while remote peer does same thing.

If I understand UDP hole punching method, sending packet from first peer (**A**) opens NAT record in **A**'s NAT and it is dropped by **B**'s NAT because of no record in NAT. So when B send packet to **A**, there is record in **A**'s NAT created with first packet (for B) and packet should be received by **B**. The NAT record in **B**'s NAT is created. **A** should send another packet to **B** successfully.

P.S.: http://nattest.net.in.tum.de/test.php test was successful 
http://nattest.net.in.tum.de/individualResult.php?hash=a5f229d156d4f5409a305c37729d9510
http://nattest.net.in.tum.de/individualResult.php?hash=3fd60e888721908a9480cd12836b97af - using VPN on second VM

P.P.S.: I'm using virtualized Windows in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a network capture trace from both endpoints and study the results. Pay close attention to port numbers on all sides, as the port number may be getting re-mapped as well as the IP address.

It is difficult to infer what are you asking.  If you are getting an ICMP error, it's possible that the NAT or endpoint wasn't ready to receive your UDP packet. Repeating the hole punching test a few more times might clear this issue up.

I suspect the port number you think the remote peer is listening on is getting mapped differently from what you think it is.  Such will be the case if you are on a symmetric NAT, which is very possible with VPN on VM.